# What causes the "Cannot find name" error in this Angular 11 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

I am working on an Angular 11 application.

In the service `UserService` I have:

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { UserModel } from '../path/to/UserModel';

export class UserService implements OnDestroy {

    public isActiveUser: boolean = false;

    public checkUserStatus(user: UserModel) {
        return this.isActiveUser;
    }

}
```

I use the above service in a component, like this:

```
import { UserService } from '../path/to/user-service.service';
    
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    public isActiveUser: boolean;

    public checkUserStatus() {
        this.isActiveUser = this.UserService.checkUserStatus(user);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

In the above CompositionEvent, on the line `this.isActiveUser = this.UserService.checkUserStatus(user)` I get the error:

> Cannot find name 'user'

##### What causes this error?

Comment: where is the variable `user` that you're passing into the function declared?

Comment: Like @TZHX told you need to pass user as a parameter. I guess you forgot to pass it your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user variable is missing in your code.

Here are scenarios to set the user variable

```js
import { UserService } from '../path/to/user-service.service';
// Import your model with below path
import { UserModel } from '../path/to/UserModel';
    
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    public isActiveUser: boolean;
// Declare your user variable
user: UserModel;

    public checkUserStatus() {
        this.isActiveUser = this.UserService.checkUserStatus(user);
    }
}
```

Resolve your error :)

Answer (score 1):

> In the above CompositionEvent, on the line this.isActiveUser = this.UserService.checkUserStatus(user) I get the error:

Coz no `user` constant / variable is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `user` variable is never defined anywhere?

Comment: The `user` variable is passed to the `checkUserStatus` method in the service.